# How is scala handling new lines when compiling?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I have here this code and everything is fine:

```
var capital = Map("US" -> "Washington", "France" -> "Paris")

println(capital("France"))
```

Now lets add some new lines after **Map** because it looks much better this way:

```
    var capital = Map
    (
        "US" -> "Washington", 
        "France" -> "Paris"
    )

    println(capital("France")) //error
```

Eclipse is giving me an error with the message: `type mismatch;  found:java.lang.String("France")  required: (?, ?) Start.scala /ScalaProject/src   line 11 Scala Problem`

Huh why that? Just because Im adding the stuff after a new line? Actually I can do this without any error message:

```
var capital = Map("US" -> "Washington", "France" -> "Paris")

println(

    capital


    (

    "France")) //no error
```

So what is the problem with **Map**? How does scala handle new lines? Im just confused.

Edit: Im using

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

Comment: You have an open parenthesis, so the compiler keeps looking until it finds the matching close, newlines or no.  What else could it sensibly do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When entering lines into the REPL (not sure about Eclipse), any line that could be valid on its own is attempted.

```
var capital = Map
```

is valid, so the rest is interpreted as a separate statement (which actually creates a Tuple2 with the mappings, and then discards them because they're not assigned to anything).  In a shell (or the REPL in `:paste` mode), it provisionally attempts to join the lines, and then everything is okay.

To get around this problem in the REPL--and to conform to idiomatic Scala style--you should leave opening braces and parentheses on the previous line:

```
var capital = Map(
  "US" -> "Washingtion",
  "France" -> "Paris"
)
```

If you have an open block of some sort, the compiler will go arbitrarily far looking for a close; the REPL (not in `:paste` mode) will bail if it finds two blank lines in a row but will skip over one.

```
val works = Map(

  1 -> "one"
)

val fails = Map(


  2 -> "two"
)
```

but note that `fails` will only fail if the line is *completely empty*; if there is even a space on the line (e.g. put there by indenting), the REPL will keep reading more lines in the hope that you're going to type more code that will finish the block.

Comment: Just wondering, why this brace problem isnt happening later with prinlnt(capital /newline/newline (